# Having trouble making cost calculator with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing vancomycin cost calculator but can not seem to figure out where am I wrong with the code. I tried JavaScript console also but can not see any errors. The goal is take all the inputs and to display results in output attribute of form but can't seem to figure out errors with in the the code.

here is the formula for cost per dose:

```
supplyCost = vancomycinCost + diluentCost + ancillaryCost;

laborCost = (pHourlyCost * pMinutesCost / 60) + (tHourlyCost * tMinutesCost / 60);

costPerDose = (supplyCost + laborCost) * (1 + wastePercentage);
```

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Vancomycin Dose Cost Calculator</title>

          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

          <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/styles.css">

        </head>

        <body>



          <form name="calc Form" id="calcform" action="">

            <h1>What is the cost of a 1 g Vancomycin dose?</h1>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Vancomycin cost: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" id="vancomycinCost" name="vancomycin" class="form-control" placeholder="$">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Diluent cost: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="diluent" id="diluentCost" class="form-control" placeholder="$">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Ancillary cost: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="ancillary" id="ancillaryCost" class="form-control" placeholder="$" onchange="calculateTotal()">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> % Waste: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="waste" id="wastePercentage" class="form-control" placeholder="%">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Pharmacy Tech: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="tHourly" id="tHourlyCost" class="form-control" placeholder="Hourly Rate"> <br>
                <input type="text" name="tMinutes" id="tMinutesCost" class=" tm form-control" placeholder="Time per dose (min)">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Pharmacist: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="pHourly" id="pHourlyCost" class="form-control" placeholder="Hourly Rate"> <br>
                <input type="text" name="pMinutes" id="pMinutesCost" class=" pm form-control" placeholder="Time per dose (min)">

              </div>
              <output class=" o btn btn-light" id="output"> </output>
              <button type="submit" class=" b btn btn-outline-light">See Result</button>
            </div>

          </form>

          <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

JavaScript (index.js):

```
            let form = document.querySelector('form');
            let output = document.querySelector('#output');
            let vancomycin = parseFloat(document.getElementById("vancomycinCost").value);
            let diluent = parseFloat(document.getElementById("diluentCost").value);
            let ancillary = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ancillaryCost").value);
            let waste = parseFloat(document.getElementById("wastePercentage").value);
            let tHourly = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tHourlyCost").value);
            let pHourly = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pHourlyCost").value);
            let tMinutes = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tMinutesCost").value);
            let pMinutes = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pMinutesCost").value);
            let supplyCost = vancomycinCost + diluentCost + ancillaryCost;
            let laborCost = (pHourlyCost * pMinutesCost / 60) + (tHourlyCost * tMinutesCost / 60);

            form.onsubmit = function(e){
              e.prevenDefault();
              let costPerDose = (supplyCost + laborCost) * (1 + wastePercentage);
              output.innerHTML = costPerDose;

            }
```

Comment: Why is your javascript outside a `script` tag?

Comment: I think @Sean has the right first question, but to go a little farther than that, your question doesn't say exactly what you're expecting and how it's different from what's actually happening.  I'm guessing that you expect something to happen with your `output` tag when you click that button, but when you click the button nothing changes at all. Is that correct?  If so, please answer Sean's questions.

Comment: *calculateTotal* is not defined

Comment: Take a look here and edit your question a bit. At a minimum you need to tell us what you want to happen and what is happening instead. There are probably other areas that can be improved also. I suspect strongly that if you try to cut this back to a minimum, reproducible example that you will come across the answer, but if not, the resulting improved questions will help us to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than a few things are wrong in this code.

1. I am assuming the `index.js` script file is what you have pasted after the HTML above - make it clear
2. `calculateTotal` is not defined. I wrote a new function - `returnCostPerDose()`, you can use that one if you need the *onChange* behaviour
3. Your calculations of `supplyCost`, `laborCost` and `costPerDose` included multiple wrong variable names - make sure you use the variable names as you declare them.
4. You are declaring your variables on load - you have to update them each time you are running a new calculation (*onChange*), or just declare them inside the calculation function.
5. If you are running the code in the browser as HTML, it is not the best practice to declare your own tags - use one of the existing ones provided in the HTML5 specs (referring to `<output>`).

Check this snippet for the bare minimum working version, and take from there to improve.

```js
var returnCostPerDose = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let vancomycin = parseFloat(document.getElementById("vancomycinCost").value);
  let diluent = parseFloat(document.getElementById("diluentCost").value);
  let ancillary = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ancillaryCost").value);
  let waste = parseFloat(document.getElementById("wastePercentage").value);
  let tHourly = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tHourlyCost").value);
  let pHourly = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pHourlyCost").value);
  let tMinutes = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tMinutesCost").value);
  let pMinutes = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pMinutesCost").value);
  let supplyCost = vancomycin + diluent + ancillary;
  let laborCost = (pHourly * pMinutes / 60) + (tHourly * tMinutes / 60);
  let costPerDose = (supplyCost + laborCost) * (1 + (waste/100));
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = costPerDose
}
```

```html
<form name="calcForm" id="calcform" action="" onSubmit="returnCostPerDose(event)">

  <h1>What is the cost of a 1 g Vancomycin dose?</h1>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Vancomycin cost: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="vancomycinCost" name="vancomycin" class="form-control" placeholder="$">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Diluent cost: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" name="diluent" id="diluentCost" class="form-control" placeholder="$">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Ancillary cost: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" name="ancillary" id="ancillaryCost" class="form-control" placeholder="$">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> % Waste: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" name="waste" id="wastePercentage" class="form-control" placeholder="%">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Pharmacy Tech: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" name="tHourly" id="tHourlyCost" class="form-control" placeholder="Hourly Rate"> <br>
      <input type="text" name="tMinutes" id="tMinutesCost" class=" tm form-control" placeholder="Time per dose (min)">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Pharmacist: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" name="pHourly" id="pHourlyCost" class="form-control" placeholder="Hourly Rate"> <br>
      <input type="text" name="pMinutes" id="pMinutesCost" class=" pm form-control" placeholder="Time per dose (min)">

    </div>
    <div class=" o btn btn-light" id="output"> </div>
    <button type="submit" class=" b btn btn-outline-light">See Result</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much for the sincere efforts and effective feedback!

Answer (score 0):

When declaring `supplyCost` you aren't using the variables you declared prior. I suggest you change your 
`let supplyCost = vancomycinCost + diluentCost + ancillaryCost;` 
to
`let supplyCost = vancomycin + diluent + ancillary;` as those were the values parsed as floats

Same thing with your `laborCost`
`let laborCost = (pHourlyCost * pMinutesCost / 60) + (tHourlyCost * tMinutesCost / 60);`
should be changed to
`let laborCost = (pHourly * pMinutes / 60) + (tHourly * tMinutes / 60);`

Your final syntax error is in the line
`let costPerDose = (supplyCost + laborCost) * (1 + wastePercentage);`
Where `wastePercentage` should be replaced with `waste`.

Ultimately, the thing to learn here is that you should use the variables you declared, as using the idname of the element will give you the actual element object rather than its value

You may have forgotten a script tag around your code aswell it seems.

**EDIT**: @Aydin4ik also shown light on the fact that you call a function that you havent made/declared in your elements "ancillaryCost" `onChange` event

Comment: Sean -  Thank you for the guidance. I can see lots of mistakes in my code. Also, I am using script tag for JavaScript as an external file, I should have specified. Again thank you!